# How can I trigger an Applecript or Automator app when a specific bluetooth device comes into range?

Tags: applescript, audio, automator, bluetooth

I have an Applescript that connects a bluetooth speaker to my Mac and switches “Play sound effects through:” to “Internal Speakers”.

I want this script to run every time I turn on my bluetooth speaker. I am currently triggering the script manually with a keyboard shortcut every time I switch the speaker on, but it would be even more convenient if I could set the script to run automatically whenever the bluetooth speaker becomes available to the Mac, preferably without using third-party software.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: 3rd party https://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/run-an-applescript-when-a-bluetooth-device-goes-in-out-of-range-on-mac/

Answer (score 6):

This is a sort of tricky thing to do if you don't want to use 3rd party software. However, with some bash and plist scripting we can get it to work!

First, in your `~/Library/LaunchAgents` folder create the following .plist file (in this case I have named it `com.my.bluetoothdetector.plist`; if you change the name, make sure to change line 4 in the file as well):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.my.bluetoothdetector</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop/script.sh</string>
    </array>
        <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The above file will call whatever script is located at `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop/script.sh` when there is a change in the Bluetooth environment. You can of course change the location of the file called from the Desktop to wherever you want (ensuring that it is a full path).

Now, we will make a bash script, which, when triggered by our `com.my.bluetoothdetector.plist` file, will check whether your device is connected. In this case, we will save this file to `/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

connectedyesorno="$(system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType | awk '/BLUETOOTHDEVICENAME/{f=1}/Connected:/ && f{print $2; exit}')"

if [ "$connectedyesorno" == "Yes" ]
then
  open /Applications/YOURAPPNAME.app
elif [ "$connectedyesorno" == "No" ]
then
  echo "Not connected..."
else
  echo "ERROR"
fi
```

Here, substitute `BLUETOOTHDEVICENAME` for the name of your device and the `/Applications/YOURAPPNAME.app` part of the `open /Applications/YOURAPPNAME.app` command for the location of the Automator/AppleScript app you want to run. You could also replace this line entirely to run any shell script you want when the device is connected which may negate the need for you to have a separate AppleScript/Automator app to be called.

Finally, use the command:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.bluetoothdetector.plist
```

This will start up the process which will check for the change in the Bluetooth environment and then call the `script.bash` when this is detected.

Now, hopefully, when you connect the Bluetooth device to your computer, after just a few seconds, your AppleScript/Automator file should run!

> I have an Applescript that connects a bluetooth speaker to my Mac...

Previously connected bluetooth devices should connect automatically to a Mac when they become available. If this isn't the case for you, maybe there is some sort of problem to do with your bluetooth settings. Have a look at [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3445529) article if the problem persists.

P.S. In the future, if you want to delete this, run the following commands:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.bluetoothdetector.plist
rm -r ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.bluetoothdetector.plist
rm -r ~/Desktop/script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I get to the launchctl command, I get the error “invalid property list”.

Comment: @Macrod That's odd, I never received that error during my testing; have you ensured you have pasted it exactly? You may also want to use Atom to make the file if you have been using TextEdit or a similar program. However, after a few google searches I came across some people having similar problems. I have made an edit to the original answer with one of the solutions as linked. Hope this solves your question! If not just do some googling around trying to find what exactly it is in the `.plist` file that is creating the error. Best

Comment: BTW I use a program called [EventScripts](http://www.mousedown.net/mouseware/EventScripts.html) by Mousedown however, it's no longer available in the US App Store (at the present time anyway). It's nice to know though how to workaround it if the current version I have stops working in macOS Mojave, when I upgrade.

Comment: @user3439894 I hadn't heard of that program before but I'll have to look into it because it looks like it has a lot of functionality! Is there not a way to get it from somewhere other than the App Store? I'm glad I was able to provide you with a possible solution assuming your program stops working when you upgrade. As I mentioned in the answer, the whole process would be simplified by using a 3rd party app like yours but it was specifically requested to use built in resources only.

Comment: @user3439894 Also, I'm sure that with some adjustments to my answer, you could modify it to trigger when other, non Bluetooth, related events occur like an SSID change. P.S. I am still confused as to why the original, flawed, '.plist' file worked for me but not for the person asking the question... odd.

Comment: When I first purchased it, it was in the US App Store. I can still download it, but it may not be the latest. As to obtaining it elsewhere, it would probably have to be an App Store from another country, as it's not directly available from the website for individual purchases. Although you can contact them if you require non-App Store versions of any of their apps for enterprise distribution. I'm not affiliated with Mousedown, just a user. As to the plist not working without the header, it may depend on the OS X/macOS version, can't say for sure with out testing, which I'm not inclined to do.

Comment: @user3439894 Unfortunately, it looks like Mousedown is unavailable in my App Store too :( Do you expect it's current functionality to cease upon upgrading to macOS Mojave? Indeed, it is strange for the plist file to work on my computer without a problem. More-so that I have been using the incorrect format for a few years now (I'm now on the newest macOS) and have never experienced a problem. Guess it wouldn't be wrong if I were to start correctly formatting all my plists the correct way even if there is no difference for me.

Comment: As to "Do you expect it's current functionality to cease upon upgrading to macOS Mojave?"... It seems with ever major OS release, and some minor releases too, some third party software have minor issues to outright breaks. So, if it does have issues or breaks and I cannot get a version that works, then I'll use the foundation presented in your answer to roll my own solutions that I current use Script Events for. Thanks.

Comment: Update, I tried again using Atom and the problem disappeared but the script doesn’t run when the device is switched on. But after a restart the Bluetooth speaker now connects automatically as it should in MacOS. If anyone can shed light on why the script didn’t run, this answer might be helpful to others.

Comment: @Macrod That is odd. Incase you haven't seen, I have updated the format for the `.plist` file in my original answer in accordance with the official Apple documentation. Do you receive any errors when doing the `launchctl`command? Also, if you just run `system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType | awk '/BLUETOOTHDEVICENAME/,0' | grep "Connected" | head -1 | sed 's/.*Connected: //'` on its own (making sure to *ONLY* replace `BLUETOOTHDEVICENAME`), do you at least get a `No`/`Yes`?

Comment: @Macrod Also, what version of macOS are you on?

Comment: I forgot to mention this the other day, if you're going to use `awk`, then there is really no need to invoke the 3 additional `pipes` and 3 additional utilities, `grep`, `head` and `sed`, they are not needed. BTW In this case, using `grep -m 1 "Connected"` negates the need for `| head -1` however, the following uses `awk` by itself to do what the additional `pipes` `grep`, `head` and `sed` were doing: `connectedyesorno="$(system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType | awk '/BLUETOOTHDEVICENAME/{f=1}/Connected:/ && f{print $2; exit}')"`

Comment: Or if you want to build on your existing `awk` _command_, you can use the following: `connectedyesorno="$(system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType | awk '/BLUETOOTHDEVICENAME/,0 {if(/Connected:/){print $2; exit}}')"`

Comment: @user3439894 Ah, thank you for that! I have to say; I'm no expert with `sed`, `grep`, `awk` etc. I usually just bodge until it works! :) However, I'll edit my original answer to swap the older, inefficient command with the one you suggested to make it cleaner.